# Узнать размеры текста до его отображения

Tags: c#, wpf

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как узнать размер текста еще до его отображения?

У меня есть массив TextBlock с текстом. Мне нужно узнать длину максимального из их, и обернуть их в Border этого размера до отображения.

Comment: Простой вопрос - зачем? Ибо кажется, будто вы делаете что-то не так.

Comment: потому-что я учусь,  и хочу узнать, как узнать размер текста до отображения

Comment: Вы не должны этого хотеть, даже в обучающих целях. В WPF есть XAML, в котором вы все и должны писать, сам WPF за вас подбирает все нужные размеры, и все выводит так, как надо. А вы вдруг хотите лезть в процесс рендеринга...

Comment: @НикитаВерталь согласен, что вы не должны этого хотеть. А так, если все-таки очень хочется, то поизучайте как в контролах работают Measure и Arrange, на них основаны все механики позиционирования контролов в WPF. Просто знание, сколько пикселей в тексте вам ничего не даст, потому что сменив монитор или настройки системы у вас может смениться DPI и все эти подсчеты насмарку. Но это и не надо считать, потому что в 100% случаев за вас легко и правильно посчитает сам WPF, надо только научиться его использовать. Забудьте про километры костылей из Winforms, они здесь не нужны.

Comment: Во https://habr.com/ru/articles/135990/

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [FormattedText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.formattedtext?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=windowsdesktop-7.0).

```
public Size GetTextPixelLength(string value, TextBlock textBlock)
{
    var formattedText = new FormattedText(
        value,
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
        FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
        new Typeface(textBlock.FontFamily,
                     textBlock.FontStyle,
                     textBlock.FontWeight,
                     textBlock.FontStretch),
        textBlock.FontSize,
        Brushes.Black,
        new NumberSubstitution(),
        VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi(textBlock).PixelsPerDip);

    return new Size(formattedText.Width, formattedText.Height);
}
```

Comment: А если `TextBlock` содержит несколько секций `<Run>` со смешанным форматированием? Получится, что неправильно посчитаете. И я все глаза сломал, не вижу, где вы `string value` используете и что такое `candidate`.

Comment: @aepot, спасибо, поправил опечатку. Касательно `Run` - отдельный вопрос, но автор не уточнял